# Laravel user can follow Comment, Category, Post etc

Tags: php, laravel-5, relational-database

I wanted to implement a follow system where a `User` can follow `Comment`, `Category`, `Post` and more. I have tried using **Laravel Polymorphic** relations for this but could not wrap my head around it. If someone can guide me it will be great.

Here is what I have tried.

**User Model**

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Category::class, 'followable', 'follows')->withTimestamps();
}
```

**Category Model**

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Follow::class, 'followable');
}
```

**Follow Model**

```
public function followable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**Follow migration**

```
Schema::create('follows', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->morphs('followable');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

How can I get the all the `categories`, `comments` followed by a user. Also how I can get the Followers of a Cateogry or Commnets etc.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont't need `Follow` model.
All you need is pivot table like so

```
followable
    user_id - integer
    followable_id - integer
    followable_type - string
```

add `folowers` method to all your classes which you need to follow

For example
**Category Model**

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'followable');
}
```

Then in **User Model**

```
public function followers()
{
    return $this->morphToMany(User::class, 'followable');
}

public function followedCategories()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Category::class, 'followable')->withTimestamps();
}

public function followedComments()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Comment::class, 'followable')->withTimestamps();
}

public function followedPosts()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Post::class, 'followable')->withTimestamps();
}

// and etc

public function followedStuff()
{
    return $this->followedCategories
        ->merge($this->followedComments)
        ->merge($this->followedPosts);
}
```

Then you can reach your goal by accessing to followers of certain category, comment or post or whatever you wish(if it followable of courcse)
For example:

```
$folowers = $category->folowers;
// will return all followers this category
$all = $user->followedStuff();
// will return collection of all things followable by the user
```

Comment: just one more thing, I can get User followers by `$user->followers` what about users followings, how can I get all the users following a user.